# How do I configured GGTS 3.4.0 to use the internally shipped Grails runtime?

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I've been using a previous version of GGTS with an externally configured Grails 2.1.1 runtime path. Upgrading to GGTS 3.4.0 I'd like to use the Grails that ships with GGTS (2.2.4), but I don't know how to configure the preferences to use the internally shipped grails version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I skip the option to install Grails from GGTS/STS when I install it - I prefer to manage that myself. Go to Window|Preferences and then to the Grails node under the Groovy node. You can easily add as many Grails installations as you want from there, and choose which one is the default.

Comment: I installed GGTS to `C:\Program Files` and found that its default Grails installation didn't like the space.  Since then I just put all my Grails installs in `C:\Grails`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I did a brand new install and noticed that a brand new install creates a grails-2.2.4 sub-directory. The upgrade does not give you the option and I assumed it would.